# How do I stop the player from rotating when they collide with a tile?

Tags: 2d, physics, rotation, touch, jumping

I use Touch movement and if I jump and hit a corner with the feet of my player, my player rotates but I don't want this. Can anyone help me jumping without rotating if I hit anything ?

here is my Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10, jumpVelocity =  10;
    public LayerMask playerMask;
    public bool canMoveInAir = true;
    Transform myTrans, tagGround;
    Rigidbody2D myBody;
    bool isGrounded = false;

    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myTrans = this.transform;   
        tagGround = GameObject.Find (this.name + "/tag_ground").transform;

        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (myTrans.position, tagGround.position, playerMask);

        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_BLACKBERRY && !UNITY_WINRT
        Move(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));   
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
           Jump();
        #endif
    }

    public void Move(float horizontalInput) 

    {
            //Er klebt nicht mehr an den Waenden
        if (!canMoveInAir && !isGrounded)
            return;

        Vector2 moveVel = myBody.velocity;
        moveVel.x = horizontalInput * speed;
        myBody.velocity = moveVel;  

        anim.SetFloat ("speed", Mathf.Abs (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x));

        if (horizontalInput < 0) 
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2 (25, 25);
        }
        if (horizontalInput > 0) 
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2 (-25, 25);
        }   
    }


    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            myBody.velocity += jumpVelocity * Vector2.up;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the rotation on the physics object that's part of your character. There's a few ways of going about that. You can do it [via scripts](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-freezeRotation.html):

```
void Start () 
{
    myBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    myBody.freezeRotation = true;
```

Or you can freeze specific axis of rotation in the Unity editor using the Inspector (found under the [constraints section](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-constraints.html)):

[image]

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Byte56's answer, you can cancel the rotation, but not lock it. If you want to stop the rotation but not necessarily freeze it, you can use `myBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero`.

This means it will stop rotating, but if a new force is applied, it will start a fresh rotation.